# C# - Split a string with spaces in between in multiple strings

Tags: c#, string

I have a string which is a sentence. For example:

```
string sentence = "Example sentence";
```

How can I divide this string into multiple strings? So:

```
string one = "Example";
string two = "sentence";
```

Comment: Have you heard of `String.Split`? You get an array which contains multiple strings. You can access them via index or use a loop to enumerate them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work

```
string sentence = "Example sentence";
string [] sentenses = sentence.Split(' ');

string one = sentenses[0];
string two = sentenses[1];
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a dupe but you are looking for string.Split (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx) --

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string sentence = "Example sentence";
        string[] array = sentence.Split(' ');

        foreach (string val in array.Where(i => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(i)))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(val);
        }
    }
}
```

The .Where ensures empty strings are skipped.